# Using Moq to mock some constructor arguments and letting Ninject take care of the rest?

Tags: unit-testing, ninject, moq

My service takes a bunch of arguments in the constructor which are normally injected by Ninject. When writing a unit test, could I mock just one of those constructor arguments and still have Ninject do the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Of course you'll need registration for all other dependencies, too (from your production code or done "manually"). Just do

```
...instanciation of kernel and registration of non-mock types

var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToConstant(fooMock.Object);

SomeTestee testee = kernel.Get<SomeTestee>();
```

If, however, `IFoo` would already be bound by production code, you could use `Rebind` to replace the binding:

```
kernel.Rebind<IFoo>().ToConstant(fooMock.Object);
```

Yet another alternative is to use the [Ninject.MockingKernel](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.MockingKernel). This provides a syntax like `Bind<IService>().ToMock();`. But you best look at the website since explaining it all here would go beyond the scope.